# Differentiability of $f$ at the origin

Tags: real-analysis

I have $$
f(x,y) = \cases{ \dfrac{\sin(x^2y^2)^{\alpha}}{x^2y+y^3}& if $y\ne0$ \\[6px]
       x& if $y=0$ \\
}
$$

The function is continuous at zero if $\alpha>\frac{3}{4}$ and $\nabla f(0,0)=(1,0)$ but how can I prove differentiability at zero?

If I use the definition
$$\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{\dfrac{\sin(h^2k^2)^\alpha}{k(h^2+k^2)}-h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$
is complicated.
Can I find a curve where $f$ isn't differentiable for $\alpha >\frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: I changed my answer; hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we look at $f$ along the curve $(x,x).$ Take your expression and let $h=k=x.$ We get

$$\frac{\dfrac{\sin[(x^4)^\alpha]}{x^3}-x}{\sqrt{2x^2}}= \frac{\sin [(x^4)^\alpha]}{x^3\sqrt 2|x|}-\frac{x}{\sqrt 2|x|}.$$

This fails to have a limit as $x\to 0 $ for $\alpha>0,\alpha \ne 1.$ (Try $3/4<\alpha < 1$ first; in this case the expression is unbounded near $0.$)

Answer (score 0):

Differentiability is for $\alpha> \frac{3}{4} $ non only 1.Using the definition is complicate.